# jQuery Selecting Elements That Have Class A or B or C

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, class, jquery-selectors

I working on something where I need two functions.

1 - I need to look at a group of children under the same parent and based on a class name, "active", add that element's ID to an array.

```
['foo-a','foo-b','foo-d']
```

2 - I then iterate through all the children in another parent and for each element I want to find out if it has any class name that match the ids in the array.

Does this element have class foo-a, foo-b or foo-d?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var active = $("#foo").find(".active").map(function() {
    return this.id;
}).get();

$("#anotherParent *").each(function() {
   var that = this;
   var classes = $(this).attr("class");
   if(classes.indexOf(" ") !== -1) {
       classes = classes.split(" ");
   } else {
       classes = [ classes ];  
   }
   $.each(classes, function(i, val) {
       if($.inArray(val, active)) {

           // this element has one of 'em, do something with it
           $(that).hide();
       }
   });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

For the first part, I'd use [`map`](http://api.jquery.com/map) and [`get`](http://api.jquery.com/get):

```
var activeGroups = $('#parent .active').map(function() {
    return this.id;
}).get();
```

This gives you an array of id values (say, `['foo-a', 'foo-d']`).  You can then make a selector like `.foo-a, .foo-b, .foo-c` (the [multiple selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector)) using [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join):

```
var activeSelector = '.' + activeGroups.join(', .');
```

This makes a valid jQuery selector string, e.g. `'.foo-a, .foo-d'`. You can then use this selector to find the elements you want using [`find`](http://api.jquery.com/find):

```
var activeEls = $('#secondParent').find(activeSelector);
```

You can then do whatever you need to with `activeEls`.

Answer (score 1):

There's always `.is('.foo-a, .foo-b, .foo-d')`. Or if you actually just wanted to select them, instead of iterating and deciding for each element, `$('.foo-a, .foo-b, .foo-d', startingPoint)`.